# Which number is different from the others? $526, 793, 382, 764, 329, 894, 932, 397, 478, 489, 652$

Tags: combinatorics

So, in a circle we have numbers $526, 793, 382, 764, 329, 894, 932, 397, 478, 489, 652$ (arranged like in the photo). The question is to find one number which is different from others.

[image]

We are given 5 options to be choose from which are :"$526, 329, 382, 793, 932$"

I dunno if the arrangement have something to do with the number or not. For the pattern I have found so far is that some numbers is the same with different arrangement: $(526, 652), (793, 397), (329, 932) , (894, 489)$. That leaves $764, 478, 382$ and $(764, 478)$ have two numbers which are the same so that leaves $382$ so is $382$ the answer of the problem?

Comment: Every one of them is different from the others.

Comment: $397$ is the odd one out because I've had friends who have had all the other numbers as their street addresses.

Comment: Petition for this problem to replace Poincaré conjecture for millennium prize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That 764 looks more like a 784 -- compare what the other sixes look like. And 784 is a rearrangement of 478. So there is even more evidence that 382 is the 'odd' man out.

Answer (score 1):

There are problably multiple answers to this as there isn't a clear criterium for being *different*. However, for what it's worth, $397$ is the only prime number in the image.

EDIT: Just realized that $397$ is not one of the options. I leave the answer here for oddity's sake unless someone wants me to delete it.

Comment: If you didn't tell me, I wouldn't know that 397 is a prime! It's a good answer despite the fact that there is no 397 in the option. You shouldn't delect this, I think. Thanks for your answer